# Prove that any function f in $L^p$ is the limit, in the metric of $L^p$, of a sequence of simple functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I know that I'll need to use dominated convergence here. 
In the problem, they ask to consider, when f is bounded and nonnegative, the sequence:

$s_n(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{i-1}{2^n}  \text{ for }  \frac{i-1}{ 2^n} \leq s(x) < \frac{i}{ 2^n} ; i = 1,2,...,n2^n\\
           n          \text{ for } s(x) \geq n
\end{cases}$

And when f is nonnegative, consider the sequence given by $$s_n = min(f,n)$$ is convergent to f in $L^p$.

I know $s_n$ in  the first case is increasing so $\int|f-s_n|^p d\mu\rightarrow0$ by dominated convergence. But I really don't know where to start in the second case with the min function. Any ideas or a proof would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Im working out the kinks for my equation. Editing now.

Comment: I've attempted to help speed along the editing process. Hopefully what I've edited it to is close to what you were trying to type.

Comment: To reiterate, what is the question?

Comment: @Sujaan Kunala : Exactly! Thanks.

Comment: @copper.hat: I need to prove the statement in the title.

Comment: You need to explain what difficulties you are having.